# String processing - improve efficiency

Tags: java, string

To print strings in which consecutive characters are different. For example, ABAA into ABA.To do this, it is allowed to delete the characters in the string. Task is to find the minimum number of required deletions. My code computes desired output for less value of T. But when T(=10) or string length become large it is Terminated due to timeout...can anyone give solution?

```
 
Input Format
The first line contains an integer T i.e. the number of test cases.
Next T lines contain a string each.

Output Format
Print minimum number of required steps for each test case.
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlternatingCharacters{

     static String removeCharAt(String s, int pos) {
          return s.substring(0, pos) + s.substring(pos + 1);
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
          int no_of_testcase=s.nextInt();
          String values="";
          int removechars;

          ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(no_of_testcase);
          for(int i=0;i<no_of_testcase;i++)
          {
               values=s.next();
               arrlist.add(values);
          }

          for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++)
          {
                removechars=0;
               for(int k=0;k<arrlist.get(i).length()-1;k++)
               {
                  if(arrlist.get(i).charAt(k)==arrlist.get(i).charAt(k+1))
                  {
                      removeCharAt(arrlist.get(i),k+1);
                      removechars++;
                  }
               }
               System.out.println(removechars);
          }

     }
}
```

Comment: Well let's describe your problem correctly. It isn't about 'terminate due to timeout', it's about how to improve the runtime of this String code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.substring(0, pos) + s.substring(pos + 1);
```

There is your problem.

You should try using char arrays instead of Strings. String concatenation is extremely slow. Put everything in a char array than change your algorithm to use that.